# How to display photos in two lines using swiper

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

i wand to display photos look like this

[image]

but what i made doesn't show the photos like this.
[image]
if i clicked the left or right side it will show the next photo.

instead of that i just want the pictures to be displayed in two or three lines.

how can i make it?
please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Code debugging needed, Share the code repo link!

Answer (score 0):

create 2 same slider wrap below one in an wrapper div (in my code `.mySwiper2`)  and pass it in as a slider when initializing main slider (in my code `.mySwiper`) .

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 4,
        freeMode: true,
        watchSlidesProgress: true,
      });
      var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        thumbs: {
          swiper: swiper,
        },
      });
```

```css
html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }

      body {
        background: #000;
        color: #000;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }

      .mySwiper2 {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .mySwiper {
        height: 20%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px 0;
      }

      .mySwiper .swiper-slide {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.4;
      }

      .mySwiper .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff"
      class="swiper mySwiper2">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
    <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-9.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```